# jfxtras circularpane width

Tags: javafx-8, jfxtras

i started to work with JFxtras CircularPane which shall appear after click on a node. This node shall then be directly in the middle of the circularpane. See following picture:

[scribble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R3zm.png)

To set the node directly in the middle and the circularpane around it. I need to know how is the width and height of the circular pane. But it always returns 0.

I'm using:

jdk8, jfxtras 8.0 r5

Hope you can help me to figure out the Size of the circularpane which will be appear after click on the node in the middle.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You will likely get more replies if you add your code, and notes as to what you've tried so far to your question. With that said, I suspect you're trying to retrieve these values in the initialize method. They will always be zero at the time that method is invoked. You should use the observable properties  of the object, and bind them to same properties of the other Node you are working with.

Comment: Adding your code would be good. I've used CircularLayout in two controls, so it does work quite well, so I need to know specifics.